# Markov chains $(Z_n)$, how to find the probability $\mathbb{P} (Z_{n+1} = i+1 \mid Z_n = i)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Sorry for my bad english.

We have a Markov chains $(Z_n)$ which follows this process :

At first, $Z_1 = 0$. Then, $Z_2 = 1$ with probability $1/2$ or $Z_2 = -1$ with probability $1/2$.

If $Z_2 = 1$, $Z_3 = 2$ with probability $1/2$ or $Z_3 = 0$ with probability $1/2$. If $Z_2 = -1$, $Z_3 = 0$ with probability $1/2$ or $Z_3 = -2$ with probability $1/2$. Etc.

I have done a drawing until the step 8 :

[image]

We would like to show that :

$\mathbb{P} (Z_{n+1} = i+1 \mid Z_n = i) = \dfrac{n+2-i}{2(n+2)}$, and

$\mathbb{P} (Z_{n+1} = i-1 \mid Z_n = i) = \dfrac{n+2+i}{2(n+2)}$

I don't see how to do it at all. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Is the formula correct if you let $n=2$ and $i=1$? According to the description before the picture, you should get $\frac12$ isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the model it appears u first take $B_i \forall i≥1$ where $B_i$ are iid random variables that take value 1 and -1 with probability 1/2 each. And ur Markov chain is
$Z_n= \sum_{i=1} ^n B_i$ Then ur $P[Z_{n+1}=j \mid Z_n=i] = 1/2 $ if $j=i+1$ or $ i-1$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Thank you ! So the two formulas are false ?

Comment: If this is the model u are following then yes.